# Where are the 'Cast' and 'Cast only' shadow options in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

[image]Where do we find those settings in Blender? I've set to Cycles, added a material but can't find these.
Is this a version issue?

[image]

Comment: I think that's an option from Blender Render, Cycles have a Shadow Catcher, hope that helps

Comment: @Emir As far as I am aware, the shadow catcher would not replicate the functionality of either of those options.

Comment: THis image is part of a shadow catcher-like technique for non-photorealistic. I'm posting the full image. But I still can't find those options...